# Call to SOAP WebService using client certificate in objective c

Tags: objective-c, web-services, ssl, soap, client-certificates

I'm a very Junior objective C developer and I'm trying to call to a SOAP web service which needs a client side certificate.

I've made the SOAP call, but server returns I need the certificate.

I've got a `.p12` file (the certificate) and I've saved it on my keychain so I can access from my browser but i don't know how to use this file on the app I'm trying to build. I've searched on Google but I can't find any working answer.

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who downvoted the question? Why? And the most important: ¿Can anyone help me? I'm still stucked at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question because no one did and i've already found the solution.

First of all, you need to save the certificate in the project's directory. Drag and drop the certificate from it's folder to the directory of the project in Xcode. Select "copy" and yes to the window that will appear.

Then, you'll need to make your project recognize the file.

Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. And add here the file.

Back to the class where you make the call:

```html
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %lu", (unsigned long)[webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//NSUTF8StringEncoding NSASCIIStringEncoding
    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);
    [theXML release];
}

- (OSStatus)extractIdentity:(CFDataRef)inP12Data :(SecIdentityRef*)identity {
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("passwd");
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };

    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12Data, options, &items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef ident = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items,0);
        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(ident, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
    }

    if (options) {
        CFRelease(options);
    }

    return securityError;
}


- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return YES;
}

OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust)
{
    OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

    CFStringRef password = CFSTR("passwd");
    const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
    const void *values[] = { password };

    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);

    if (securityError == 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
        tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
        *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
        const void *tempTrust = NULL;
        tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
        *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
    }

    if (options) {
        CFRelease(options);
    }

    return securityError;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"Authentication challenge");

    // load cert
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameOfFile" ofType:@"p12"];// If it's not working Targets > Build phases > Copy bundle Resources
    NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    CFDataRef inP12data = (__bridge CFDataRef)p12data;

    SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
    SecTrustRef myTrust;
    OSStatus status = extractIdentityAndTrust(inP12data, &myIdentity, &myTrust);

    SecCertificateRef myCertificate;
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate(myIdentity, &myCertificate);
    const void *certs[] = { myCertificate };
    CFArrayRef certsArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, certs, 1, NULL);

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity certificates:(__bridge NSArray*)certsArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Then run!